# All tr in table are even

Tags: css, pug

My trouble is: all rows in my table are even!
I make rows within Jade mixin, here is the code:

```
mixin add_table_rows(books, rows)
- for (var i=0; i < rows; i++) {
  tr
    td
    - each obj in books[i] 
      td= obj
    td
      button.table-button.edit    edit
      button.table-button.delete  delete
-}

table.books-list 
 tr
 -for object in tableHeaders 
  th= object
 +add_table_rows(books, rows_count)
```

So when i use next css code all rows colored in #111

```
  .books-list tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #111;
  }

  .books-list tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f2b910;
  }
```

Comment: How does the generated HTML structure look like?

Comment: i dont know... how can i watch it? i can make screenshoot, table is made as i need but this issue

Comment: You can see the table in a browser right? Just right-click and select “View Page Source”. You should know what the code results in, if you want to debug anything…

Comment: thx really, every 1st tr are empty! will look a bug in loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug is in this code, one tr is excess, code must looks like here

```
  table.books-list 

  -for object in tableHeaders 
   th= object
  +add_table_rows(books, rows_count)
```